# Automatically Return to Upload View Controller after Selecting the Image IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi in my application I'm uploading the image form the  device to server the problem is after selecting the image its not automatically going back to the upload page in my application i have done like once image selected  you have click the cancel button then only it will go the upload view. What i want once i select the image i want to go back to my upload page automatically so then it will be more user friendly. Please tell me is that possible. Its possible means  what is right method to do it.

Image Upload code.

```
  NSString *urlString = @"url";

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init]autorelease];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] ;
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
  NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
  [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

  NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [request setHTTPBody:body];

  NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
  NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSLog(@"%@data",returnString);
```

image pick controller code.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
     [picker.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     imageview.image = image;
   }
```

Its showing like this.

Please tell in the above code where i have to add the method to return back the upload view code in this above code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    imageview.image = image;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```